# for loop firestore query in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm trying to query all documents that match the value that I get from the variable array `this.user.userActivities`. The code works, but I only get 1 value after I *ngFor the observable (`this.savedActs`) that I save the data in.

```
for await (const item of this.user.userActivities) {
  this.savedActs = await this.store.collection<ResultCard>('activities', ref => ref
  .where('uid', '==', item.path.replace('activities/', ''))).valueChanges();
}
```

I cant figure out how the forloop affects the query, but i'm sure that it's the culprite.

**UPDATE**
I want to add that I've tried something like this but I don't know why i dont get the data to persist out of the for loop

```
for (const item of user.userActivities) {
  this.afStore.doc<ResultCard>(item.path).get().subscribe((v) => {
    console.log(v.data());
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore structure and explain your query?

Comment: this is my firestore structure https://imgur.com/YKj63jZ. With the query I have all the user data stored to variable `this.user` so i'm iterating trough the array of `this.user.userActivities` so I get the path for that specific activity. Then im going trough 'activities' firestore collection(https://imgur.com/JUUsUcO) and getting all the items with uid == item.path+some trimming